# How to create "something" like a REST API without HTTP?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, service, architecture

First of all, I'm sorry for the poor title.

I'd like to have `my_api_service.py` running as a **background service**, which works *similar* to a **REST-API** for other scripts, but **without HTTP**.

Scripts on **different virtual environments** running on **different Python instances** should be able to use `my_api_service.py` via `my_api_connector.py`.

I hope my question is **not opinion-based** as I'm looking for a common/best practice/pattern.

*The following is pseudocode.*

**my_api_service.py** *- Python instance 1*

```
# Singleton
instance = None
def instance():
    if not instance:
        self.instance = MyGlobalService()
    return instance

# Title setter
def set_title(title):
    self.instance.set_title(title)

# Title getter
def get_title(title):
    return self.instance.get_title()
```

**print_current_title.py** *- Python instance 2*

```
from my_api_connector import get_instance

while True:
    # The title should change when set_title.py was executed
    title = get_instance().get_title()
    print('Current title: {0}'.format(title))
```

**set_title.py** *- Python instance 3*

```
from my_api_connector import get_instance
get_instance().get_title('New title')
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using sockets?

Comment: Maybe using Websockets or MQTT.

Comment: @HoracioGoetendia I was thinking about something *lower* than Sockets or MQTT, very close to the OS. Do you know an alternative?

Comment: Can you please tell us the goal of using lower mechanism in Python? Seems like XY problem, you know. If you worry about performance, Python is not a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with usage of sockets.

client.py:

```
import my_api_connector

print(my_api_connector.get_title())  # will print title
my_api_connector.set_title('another_title')
print(my_api_connector.get_title())  # will print another_title
```

my_api_connector.py:

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 12345
SOCK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def get_title():
    SOCK.sendto(b'get_title', (IP, PORT))
    data, _ = SOCK.recvfrom(1024)
    return str(data, 'utf-8')

def set_title(title):
    SOCK.sendto(bytes('set_title {}'.format(title), encoding='utf-8'), (IP, PORT))
```

server.py:

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 12345
SOCK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
SOCK.bind((IP, PORT))

def main():
    title = 'title'
    while True:
        data, addr = SOCK.recvfrom(1024)
        data = str(data, 'utf-8')
        if data == 'get_title':
            SOCK.sendto(bytes(title, encoding='utf-8'), addr)
        elif data.startswith('set_title'):
            title = data[len('set_title '):]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just start server.py in one console and then client.py in another.

Comment: Thank you. Sockets could be a solution, but I was hoping for something without any network and fully local and close to the operating system, but I don't know if it exists. Do you know an alternative to Sockets?

Comment: The code I provided is fully local, it doesn't require Internet connection to execute.

Comment: @Mr.B.Shared Memory or Pipes could be, in general any IPC mechanism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication.

Comment: @Sanyash You're right, but it *feels* not "low level" enough. :)

Comment: @HoracioGoetendia I never heard about *IPC* before. Interesting, thank you!